# Delete unnecessary files/dirs right after packaging

Tags: maven

I'm building a jar file which contains the dependencies that I need. Next to the jar file I added a properties file and a batch file to start the jar with some basic params.
The main problem was, that my target dir was kind of messy with all the unnecessary files/directories which were created when building the package. I've already added the clean plugin to delete the files that I don't need:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>target</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/Test-jar-with-dependencies.jar</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/test.properties</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/ExecuteTest.bat</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Now a new problem showed up: I've overwritten the clean command so I can't clean up everyting.
Is there a way I only can call clean:unnecessary or anything else to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to call your customized clean / package only when needed and default to the "normal" clean otherwise.

Edit:
Just surround the build tag with a profile like this:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
  <id>packClean</id>

  <build>...</build>

  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Call the new created profile with: mvn < phase > -PpackClean
Complete clean available with old mvn clean

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.
To add more infos I've edited you answer.